# Why doesn't CDate(integer) work where integer has format of YYYYMMDD?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Why doesn't `CDate(integer)` work where integer has format of `YYYYMMDD` ?

and why won't this stupid site let me submit such a short question when I have nothing else to add except some waffle at the end

1 > 2 blah etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integers aren't supported, per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Use the [`IsDate` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.information.isdate.aspx) to determine if a value can be converted to a
>   date and time. CDate recognizes date literals and time literals but
>   not numeric values.

This returns `false`:

```
Dim isValid = IsDate("20120314") ' false
```

You can use a valid date representation as a string, however. Example:

```
Dim result = CDate(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Answer (score 4):

What Ahmad said.  In addition, you can use the [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) function in your particular example...

```
Dim Value As Integer = 20120314

Dim MyDate As DateTime
If DateTime.TryParseExact(Value.ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, MyDate) Then
    'Do what you want with MyDate.  For example...
    Console.WriteLine(MyDate.ToShortDateString())
End If
```

The beauty part of all the `TryParse` and `TryParseExact` functions is they simply return a Boolean value indicating that the parsing passed or failed.  They do not throw an exception.